# Postgresql - Count / Insert on table A blocks table B even though A has no FK relation with B

Tags: postgresql, locks

Postgresql - So we have two tables A and B. Inserts or counts on table B are blocking table A and I cannot understand why.

Find out who blocks A:

```
SELECT
    activity.pid,
    activity.usename,
    activity.query,
    blocking.pid AS blocking_id,
    blocking.query AS blocking_query
FROM pg_stat_activity AS activity
JOIN pg_stat_activity AS blocking ON blocking.pid = ANY(pg_blocking_pids(activity.pid));
```

[image]

Yesterday I dropped a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from table B to table A. That foreign key was not pointing to any columns updated by "query" in the image above. Dropping that doesn't seem like it made any difference.

We are using PostgreSQL 11

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: By mistake, I updated the tags. Thanks

Comment: What is the sate of the blocking sessions (identified through `blocking_id`)? If those aren't `active` then it's something else they did in their transaction. `pg_stat_activity.query` only shows the currently running query if that session has `state = active` otherwise it's just the last query executed by that session. So `AS blocking_query` should actually be `AS last_query`

Comment: Most likely one update blocks another. can you show the condition where?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - interesting, so that's the last_query. Yes, the state is active for those.

Comment: @arutar - ```UPDATE "A" SET "RANDOM_COLUMN" = 584540, "updated_at" = '2022-01-21 10:31:45.902009' WHERE "A"."id" = 237090```

Comment: It could still mean that a _previous_ statement in that transaction changed the rows. The row is blocked by a session, not by a statement.